# How to recognize two different word in a regex without grouping

Tags: regex

I've got a Regex question, I have to recognize tokens in a text that are like:

`Foo-` followed by either `bar` or `baz` followed  by `-` then some numbers, like:

```
Foo-bar-010
Foo-baz-101
```

I then want to divide my matches like : `Foo-bar`  `-010` and `Foo-baz`  `-101`

My regex is this one:

```
(Foo-(bar|baz))-[0-9]+
```

Which is kinda cool, but I don't want to define a group for the 'bar' or 'baz' clause, since it messes my results.

Any idea to get this result with only one group?

Comment: FYI, `\b` isn't doing any good in this regex. It's mainly for when you don't know what the non-word character is--like when you want to find a word that might be surrounded by whitespace, by punctuation, or by nothing at all.

Comment: It works indeed without the \b anchor. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Removed the \b anchor, as advised by Alan M

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(Foo-\b(?:bar|baz)\b)-[0-9]+
```

?: usually flags the group as a non-capturing match (depending on your engine).

Comment: Excellent.  That's a new one to me too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want.

This returns the *Foo-* and *-NNN* parts as separate groups:

```
(Foo-ba[rz])(-\d+)
```

Getting the whole thing back as a single group can be done like this.

```
(Foo-ba[rz]-\d+)
```

Comment: Yeah, granted, it sticks with the question's inputs, but my real case problem uses words slightly more distant than bar and baz ;o) thanks anyway.